# How do I overcome a "NameError: name 'x' is not defined" when I am trying to break a while loop when asking for input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a lap timer which prompts for lap times until the user enters a lap time of “x”. When I enter an if loop to break for x it gives me the name error

```
#Enhancd laptimer w/ list

laps=[]
lapcount=0

while True:
    lapcount=+1
    result = input("Enter lap time for lap %s (push x to end): " % lapcount)
    if result==x:
        break
    laps.append(result)

laps.sort()

print("Fastest lap was", laps[0])
print("Slowest lap was", laps[-1])
print("Average lap was", sum(laps)/len(laps))
```

This is the error message I receive:

```
if result==x:
```

NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Comment: You mean `if result=='x':`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access a variable named `x`, which doesn't exist. You just need to add quotes so that you compare the user input with the string "x":

```
if result=="x"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add quotes:

```
if result=='x'
```